# Why do Dialog classes have a TelemetryClient property?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, botframework

The Dialog class in the Microsoft Bot Framework has a property called TelemetryClient. This property is used to store a specific telemetry client for the dialog.

I would like to know what kind of logging is being done by the telemetry client in the dialog class? How is this property meant to be used?

Javascript:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-dialogs/dialog?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#telemetryclient

C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialog.telemetryclient?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Dialog_TelemetryClient

The property might only be used to control logging at the dialog level. That being; the telemetry client property is only accessed by the logging middleware. I have taken a look at the javascript source for Dialog object construction and also the ComponentDialog construction. What I have found supports this hypothesis because I found nothing but assignment and access logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogs have TelemetryClient class **to offer insights into your bot by showing which features are used the most, detects unwanted behavior and offers visibility into availability, performance, and usage**. Telemetry logging enables bot applications to send event data to telemetry services such as Application Insights.

- TelemetryLoggerMiddleware, TelemetryLuisRecognizer, TelemetryQnAMaker, and SkillConfiguration use Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient. It is recommended to get an instance of TelemetryClient from the dependency injection container. TelemetryClient is thread-safe. **TelemetryClient class sends events, metrics and other telemetry to the Application Insights service**. TelemetryClient() initializes a new instance of the TelemetryClient class. You can send telemetry with the active configuration, usually loaded from ApplicationInsights.config.
- TelemetryClient instance is used to report the automatically generated telemetry. The telemetry client used for sending all types of telemetry. **It serves as the main entry point for interacting with the Application Insights service**. TelemetryClient is automatically injected to DI when you configure Application Insights using either .UseApplicationInsights() or AddApplicationInsights() methods. You can use constructor injection to get the TelemetryClient instance. Application Insights telemetry client has an in-memory buffer and a flush interval (default of 1 minute) for sending the buffered telemetry to AI endpoint.

The Bot Framework provides the TelemetryClient but also allows the users to provide their own so they can change what gets logged.

Hope this helps.